# Finite group - binary

Tags: finite-groups, coding-theory

Prove that $g(\alpha)$=0 if and only if $g'(\alpha)$=0

$g(t)=t^{11}+t^{10}+t^6+t^5+t^4+t^2+1$
$g'(t)=t^{11}+t^9+t^7+t^6+t^5+t+1$

where $\alpha \in F[t]$. We are working in standard binary space.

This is the answer:

$\alpha^{11}+\alpha^{10}+\alpha^6+\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^2+1=0$
 if and only if
$1+\alpha^{-1}+\alpha^{-5}+\alpha^{-6}+\alpha^{11}+\alpha^{-7}+\alpha^{-9}+\alpha^{-11}=0$

I can't seem to get to it??

Comment: $\alpha^{11}+\alpha^{10}+\alpha^6+\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^2+1$ and $1+\alpha^{-1}+\alpha^{-5}+\alpha^{-6}+\alpha^{11}+\alpha^{-7}+\alpha^{-9}+\alpha^{11}$ aren't statements, so it makes no sense to put *if and only if* between them. Something must be missing here.

Comment: Sure. But is there any connection between these two 'equations'(non statements) ?

Comment: The latter is the former divided by $\alpha^{11}$. Not sure how that's an answer though.

Comment: @Kiv, they are not equations. An equation has two sides separated by an equality sign.

Comment: Ok, feel free to delete this post.... as it's probably no help to anyone but me and this practice paper for algebraic coding theory... i fail to see where the $\alpha^{11}+\alpha^{-7}+\alpha^{-9}+\alpha^{-11}$ bit comes from ...

Comment: @anon: Doesn't the second one have an extra $\alpha^{11}$ term?

Comment: @Brian: Ah, I didn't look closely enough. They are not related by a simple division.

Comment: Sorry I edited as I realise they were actually equations

Comment: I seem to have made the same mistake. I've been on autopilot after making the observation that the two polynomials are reciprocals of one another.

Comment: I can't see that the two are reciprocals of each other !

Comment: @Kiv, I edited my answer to show that bit in detail.

Comment: What is *binary space* for you? According to Mathematic both $g(t)$ and $g'(t)$ are irreducible. This means that their zeros are in the finite field $GF(2048)$. That is a quotient ring of the polynomial ring $F[t]$, but not a subset. So the condition $\alpha\in F[t]$ feels misguided.

Comment: $\alpha$ lies in the field containing F

Comment: What is $F$? I'm assuming that it is the field of two elements? But you shouldn't keep such things as secrets, when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that $g(t)$ and $g'(t)$ are reciprocals of each other: 
$$
t^{11} g(1/t)=t^{11}(t^{-11}+t^{-10}+t^{-6}+t^{-5}+t^{-4}+t^{-2}+1)=1+t+t^5+t^6+t^7+t^9+t^{11}=g'(t).
$$ 
This **does** mean that if one of them has a zero in some field, then so does the other. 
However, you seem to claim that the zeros coincide (you denote the common zero by $\alpha$). This is false in general. It could be true in some particular case, if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ should be a factor of both $g$ and $g'$. That is not the case here, as a quick run of Euclid's algorithm shows that the two polynomials have no common factors.

[Edit] A correct claim is that if $g(\alpha)=0$, then $g'(1/\alpha)=0$. As $g(t)$ is irreducible in $F_2[t]$ so is $g'(t)$. They both have eleven zeros in the field $GF(2048)$, but none of them are common because $\gcd(g(t),g'(t))=1$. [/Edit]

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen for the detailed answer ! i can see that they are recipricols. If the zeroes coincide because the minimal polynomial is a factor of both - I still can't see the connection between my two equations in the "solution"

Comment: @Kiv, the concensus seems to be that your latter equation has an extraneous $\alpha^{11}$. Please check your book!

Comment: argh ! I get completely ruined by typos. Sorry everyone ! But thank you in any case